# NpgSql - How to pass parameter into DO block in PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to use a parameter passed into a PostgreSQL query inside a DO block within that query. It fails though, and seems to be parsing the statement as if the parameter was a column. Is it possible to reference a query parameter in this way?

Here is my C# code (using Npgsql and Dapper as well):

```
private static async Task ParameterInDoBlock(IDbConnection postgresConn)
{
    DynamicParameters queryParams = new DynamicParameters();
    queryParams.Add("some_variable", 123);
    
    //example of successfully using a parameter    
    string sql = @"SELECT @some_variable;";
    var row = await postgresConn.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<dynamic>(sql, queryParams);
    Console.WriteLine($"Simple select: {row}");

    //this one unexpectedly fails
    sql = @"
    DO
    $$
    BEGIN
        IF @some_variable = 1 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'blah';
        END IF;
    END
    $$;";
    await postgresConn.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<dynamic>(sql, queryParams);
    /*
    Exception data:
     Severity: ERROR
     SqlState: 42703
     MessageText: column "some_variable" does not exist
     InternalPosition: 2
     InternalQuery: @some_variable = 1
     Where: PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at IF
     File: parse_relation.c
     Line: 3633
     Routine: errorMissingColumn
    */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters can only be used in `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`. I can think of two solutions:

1. write a database function in PL/pgSQL, have the parameter be a function parameter and use a parameterized statement in a `SELECT` statement that calls the function
2. compose a string that contains the actual value instead of a parameter and execute that (but take care that your code is not vulnerable to SQL injection)

Answer (score 1):

@Laurenz-Albe, thanks for the answer. I liked the first option better (prefer parameterized queries), so here is what I would end up with:

```
sql = @"
--create temp function to hold code
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.some_function(x int) RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    --just the example code I was trying to do before
    IF x = 1 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'blah';
    END IF;
END
$$;

SELECT pg_temp.some_function(@some_variable);
";
await postgresConn.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync<dynamic>(sql, queryParams);
```